# Admin block listing showing unwanted debug info

Tags: 8

Suddenly my Drupal 8 admin panel is displaying some unwanted objects/arrays in different places. Below is a screenshot of the block layout page.

This is a localhost site that is not available to public.

[image]

Comment: Is some sort of debugging happening? This is not normal.

Comment: Can you please let me know how I should check if any debugging feature is on?

Comment: Current admin theme is 'seven' and if I change it to 'stark' the above info block disappears. If this was a bug in 'seven' theme, can I repair this theme?

Comment: Yeah, simply replace it with one from a freshly downloaded Drupal. Or maybe you are using `drupal-composer/drupal-project`, then I think this is going to be fixed after running `composer install` once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like someone put a `print_r` or similar debugging call into your copy of Seven. If you are using git (which your project should be) you will be able to see the change in that tool and undo it.  The other solution would be to download a fresh copy of Drupal and replace the files in the core directory with the ones in the fresh copy.

If there are multiple people working on the project, ask around about who was testing out ideas and ask them to undo the changes to the admin theme.